# PostgreSQL Schemas -- Usage Scenario/Case

Tags: database, database-design, postgresql

I apologize for my newbie like question but I am a newbie to PostgreSQl and schemas.  I have a hard time grasping the purpose of schemas in PostgreSQL.. and in general.  What are the potential use-cases for schemas?

The book I have states that schemas are like directories that can't be nested.  OK, so I take it schemas are a means to group tables in a db.  The book does not address how this is implemented, nor does it mention the potential uses except for one trivial example (next paragraph).

**A Benefit & Potential use case #1**

Thus far I have only understood one (seemingly trivial) benefit to schemas.  This benefit being that you can have multiple tables with the same name and as long as each such table is in a different schema, there will be no conflict because the namespace qualifier (the schema name) can be used to address the particular table desired.

I don't really understand why you would have multiple tables of the same name to begin with. I'd think this is an extremely rare case, yet the docs come accross to me as if schemas should be used by everyone.  Having multiple tables of the same name seems like poor project management to me and allowing for such bad practice doesn't seem like value.
In the end you are just allowing for a mess to be made.

The only scenario I can think of where you could have name conflicts of tables which should be allowed is when you have a class that is learning SQL and the school IT admin wants each student to be able to create tables of their liking. Of course, the question in my mind is why doesn't the admin just create 1 db per student rather than 1 db for all and 1 schema for each student?  **Q1:** Why?

What are some other use cases that show the benefit of schemas?

**IMPLEMENTATION - OR - NATURE OF**

I'm also confused about the implementation/nature of schemas.
Let us assume that we have 1 DB which has 3 schemas. 1 schema per user as such:
**user1='admin'**  -- tableA, tableU, tableJ, tableK,
**user2='joe**'  ------ tableU, tableJ,
**user3='kate** ----- tableU, tableK.

In the above example, my intention is for **tableU** to be shared between the users (accross the schema joe & schema kate).  They shouldn't get their own stand-alone copy of the table, they should share common access to this table.  This type of usage makes sense to me.  Users should be adding/modding/potentially removing records... not adding/modding/removing tables.  I am not sure however that this is possible with PostgreSQL schemas.  **Q2:** If I wanted to share tableU as I described above, would schema joe & schema kate each get thair own copy of the table or can I specify that they should not get their own copy and instead just share access to an existing table?

**tableJ** is the **same** as **tableK**... except that Kate can't use tableJ and joe can't use tableK.  This seems to be the essence of schemas to me according to my limited understanding of schemas.  **Q3:** What is the purpose of making a copy of a table for each user?  The 2 tables have the same structure (columns and constraints) and it is a waste of storage space to make a stand alone copy of such a table for each user.  I'd also think that it would be nightmare if each user had their own copy of every table.  We'd be throwing key concepts like normalization out the window.  It would be an unmaintainable mess.  In my mind each user should be adding/modifying/ removing records to a common table in a common DB.

I've seen people in my Google searches about schemas make a separate schema+tables for each online customer to their website.  They have like 100,000 schemas.  **Q4:** What am I missing here?  This seems extreme to say the least.  They should be adding record(s) to standard table(s) for each customer not making schemas and tables for each customer. This only adds to my confusion.

Anyway, I hope I've stated the key points of my confusion clearly enough.

What I'm looking for is:
(1) To clear up the benefits of schemas via realistic use case examples.
(2) To clear up the implementation detail of schemas.

---

**EDIT v.3**

**Potential use case #2**

If I understood Neville K correctly, he suggest as a use case:

1 DB which has 3 schemas. 1 schema per user as such (username==schema_name in ex.):
**user1='admin'**  -- tableA, tableLogin, tblFin1, tblFin2, tblFin3, tblPrj1, tblPrj2, tblPrj3.
**user2='joe**'  ------ tableLogin, tblFin1, tblFin2, tblFin3
**user3='kate** ----- tableLogin, tblPrj1, tblPrj2, tblPrj3.

Here, joe is in Fin department, and Kate is project manager.  The app that joe uses is restricted to Finance related tables, the application that kate uses is restricted to project management tables.  This restriction is enforced via their user name being tied to a schema which is tied to a search path (enforced at DB level).

**Q5:** Wouldn't the same restriction be in place without schemas?  What tables are available to which application is a function of what tables were set to be used by the application at the time the application was made by the dev team. No?  Or are we assuming that we are using off the shelf applications that you point to a db and we are concerned that the application can not in its settings be restricted to certain tables (and this restriction locked with a password within the off-the-shelf application)?

**Potential use case #3**

If I understood Catcall correctly, he suggest as a use case:

A scenario where you wish to rent/lease the services of a database server hosted on 1 physical system to multiple customers needing database service. As such, a multi-tenant like scenario arises.  At this point you can choose to have:
(1) A separate database for each tenant (customer)
  -More secure and convenient but can support less tenants per system.
(2) One shared database with a schema for each tenant (customer)
  -Less secure and slightly less convenient but can support more tenants per system.

**Potential use case #4**

If I understood Scott Marlowe and Catcall correctly, another use case would be:

Using schemas to isolate the new content of developers during development.  Later can merge work to another schema.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I've seen people in my Google searches
>   about schemas make a separate
>   schema+tables for each online customer
>   to their website. They have like
>   100,000 schemas. Q3: What am I missing
>   here? This seems extreme to say the
>   least. They should be adding record(s)
>   to standard table(s) for each customer
>   not making schemas and tables for each
>   customer.

One database per tenant (customer) is easy to build, and it gives you the strongest isolation between tenants, and the simplest disaster recovery. But it's relatively expensive.

One schema per tenant is also easy to build. There's a smaller degree of isolation between tenants. A dbms can support more tenants per server with one schema per tenant than with one database per tenant. Disaster recovery for one tenant is more complicated than with one database per tenant.

A shared schema requires every row to have a tenant identifier. Hardware and backup are cheaper; disaster recovery for one tenant can be a real bitch. (To recover data for a single tenant, you have to recover some rows in every table. Performance suffers for all tenants when that happens.) Isolation is trickier.  Since tenants share tables, making sure no tenant can access other tenants data is a lot harder than with one database or one schema per tenant.

The search term for this stuff is "multi-tenant database design". SO also has a [multi-tenant](/questions/tagged/multi-tenant) tag.

Another common use is to group database objects that belong together. For example, if you were developing an accounting database, all the objects that implement "accounts payable" features might go in the "ap" schema. I use schemas for PostgreSQL extensions, too. In my db, I installed the hstore extension in the "hst" schema, the tablefunc extension in the "tbf" schema, etc.

Comment: Thanks (+).  I take it that both the "One database per tenant" case and the "One schema per tenant" case  can be exemplified by a scenario of some sort of service provider (like a web hosting service provider) that wants to share physical hardware between customers needing database features for the back end of their website.  Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: Yes. It's more likely to be a SaaS provider (Software as a Service) than a web hosting service. For example, services like Basecamp (basecamp.com) often have a multi-tenant database architecture on the back end.

Comment: This is a question unrelated to your excelent answer, where did you read about the `[tag:name](link)` trick?

Answer (score 13):

Here's another common usage I've seen.  Schemas and `search_path` allow two or more developers to work on the same single copy of a large db without needing their own copies, but without getting in each other's way.

Let's say Joe is working on the comments table, and Jim is working on the workflow table.  They both need the users, groups, etc tables.  Joe creates a schema, creates his own working version of the comments table, and can muck about with it at will:

```
create schema joe;
create table joe.comments (rest of new tabledef here);
set search_path='joe','public';
```

Now when Joe does `alter table` on the `joe.comments` table, Jim sees no changes and his development is not impacted by a broken `joe.comments` table etc.  When Joe's code, having a search_path of `'joe','public'` runs, it sees joe's comments tables while everyone else sees the original.

After thorough testing, Joe's comments table can be basically put in place of the original in one fell swoop with no interruption to Jim's development. Multiply this time 40 developers and it allows all 40 to work on the same dev db without blowing each other's stuff up (or less often at least).

Comment: Thanks (+).  Interesting use case.  Sounds a little dangerous though.  Although Joe prob would not mess up the existing public.comments (or production.comments) table there is a chance he could mess up the other production tables.  I'd think working off a copy of a backup copy of the production table with the scheme you describe would be safer... but that doesn't really change the nature of the scheme.  That way also they could be doing dev on a diff physical sys because 40 developers could bring perf down on the prod db quite a bit. --out of room...

Comment: ...The other thing is, like you said, Joe won't get in Jim's face, but I think this assumes that Joe is modding a table or tables that Jim is depending on to have exist and have a certain structure.  So if Joe is changing the structure of the comments joe.comments table and Jim is working on jim.workflow table but Jim depends on the structure of the old production.comments table... then sure, they won't get in each others way durring dev... but when joe is ready to replace the production.comments table with joe.comments then Jim's new production.workflow table will...

Comment: ..not work because inconsistencies were isolated and thus hidden within the schemas rather than brought to light.  I think they would have to deploy both joe.comments to production.comments and jim.workflow to production.workflow before they see if things work or not.  Of course, this would be way too risky.  I think the best way would be to dev off of a copy of a backup without schemas using good communication and good prj management... but if task is large and time is short...

Comment: ...with good comm it could work with schemas if done in 3 stages. 1st just concentrate on bulk work (using schema isolation), 2nd fix inconsistencies(deploy all tables to non-production production schema). 3rd deploy dev production schema tables to in use production system.

Comment: It's the 2nd stage that is kind of iffy in my mind.  I think such a scheme allows too much freedom in stage 1 and thus stage 2 could be a real nightmare because there could be many tables and multiple inconsistencies if 40 developers are using this method.  Tracking down inconsistencies that accumulated could be a real nightmare.  I'll wait for your comments/suggestions and then I'll add it to the list.

Comment: The point is that any tables joe needs to edit go into joe's schema.  He never touches the public schema table's definitions.  Also, jim is unlikely to be doing anything very interesting with the tables joe is playing with, as they'd be working on different sections of code and / or the database.  of course you have to check for inconsistencies, that's what staging and / or QA databases are for.  I'm strictly talking about using such a method on the dev database, which is often burnt to the ground and restarted if things go horribly wrong.

Comment: Of course you can have > 1 dev database, but using schemas reduces the need to have a bunch of isolated databases, one per developer during development work.  Then, when joe thinks his stuff is ready it migrates it to the public schema and runs whatever unit tests he's got to make sure it works.  Then, after everyone's sure it works, you promote to QA / testing etc...

Answer (score 11):

Neville K's answer captures the essence but is perhaps a bit brief.

Schemas are essentially namespaces. They're useful in the same kinds of situations that namespaces are useful in programming: where you have many things, so many that you want to partition them into separate sub-collections (many -- but fewer than (say) 10,000 such sub-collections, given that there's a single level), while being able to inter-operate among them.  Using schemas can allow more 'natural' naming standards for other database objects.

As an aside, the value of namespaces isn't appreciated by new programmers either. That seemingly trivial benefit of allowing multiple objects to have the same name isn't so trivial, it turns out. It's only when one has worked for a while on larger projects (with thousands of 'code objects': tables, views, indices, stored procedures, domains, etc.) that one comes to understand that the benefits of namespaces outweigh their costs.

In an earlier age (and not with PostgreSQL), I worked for a computer bureau with about 20 customers, ranging from 250 concurrent users of the DBMS down to one, each via private leased telephone lines. (This was before the internet.) Each customer had its own schema, with an admin user (role) that could create and drop other users as employees came and went, grant and revoke privileges, and do a limited amount of data definition work and import/export in their own schema. As a developer I had to use schemas because there was only one DBMS instance and one database. So... if the above is not convincing, you could say that schemas are in the SQL standard (for historical reasons), therefore PostgreSQL has support for schemas.

Today, a somewhat similar situation to mine might arise in a lab environment, where several researchers (or hundreds of students) each want to work on their own data while having access to a common set in the public schema. Using schemas helps stop accidents: inadvertently trampling on each others' data.

Answer (score 8):

The key benefit for schemas is to provide a logical grouping for your database tables. The most likely use cases are:

- To run different logical applications
  within the same DB - for instance,
  you might have an enterprise system,
  and want to create schemas called
  "userprofiles", "projects", "finance"
  etc.
- To create similar versions of the same group of tables, for instance for "development", "qa" and "production"

Comment: Or versioning in general to provide backward compatibility? Although that would be a nightmare to maintain. But it's a good point, when grouping applications in the same DB (such as third party applications), you don't have to worry about tables and object names conflicting- seeing as how you can't control how the third party names things.

Comment: Thanks for the post guys.  As far as the "qa","production" tables go... what would be the benefit of having 1 DB with the full spectrum of tables under the "qa" schema and then again the full spectrum of tables under the "production" schema?  You could make 1 db for "qa" and 1 db for "production", no?  I would think that this later method is superior because the "production" can be placed on a separate physical system and it probably should be for performance reasons anyway, no?  I wouldn't want the dev team bring the production system down to crawl.

Comment: ...Then when "qa" is done, just dump the "qa" db and restore the dump to the "production" db/system.

Comment: You can place schemas and / or individual tables on different storage media, you're not stuck doing it by database.  Separating things out by database means you are purposely isolating the two datasets from each other, as in you can't join one database's tables against another.  this is often a good thing.  You don't want someone to fat finger something on a test data set and destroy production.  OTOH, it's great for mixing parts of various data sets so each users sees something different from every other user.

Comment: Thanks, interesting to know that you can make a schema and configure tables created by schema owner to be made on a different physical disc.  I take it they  would still have to be on the same system though.  Is this something you state in the create schema syntax or is this hdd affinity set some other way?

Comment: The "dev/qa/production" schema thing may not make as much sense now as it did when hardware was expensive - but you might still want to give each developer their own schema on the same server.